# How far away from you does grass spread?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making one of those new 1.14 wool farms and I want it to be pretty big. Since the SMP server I play on has a max of 40 entities per chunk it has to be pretty big in terms of x and z coordinates. So basically these farms are mostly limited by the max distance in which grass spreads, I need to know how far from you grass stops spreading to find the ideal afk spot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grass spread is controlled by "random ticks". These happen when the center of the chunk section (16×16×16) is within 128 blocks of a player. That means that grass spreads in a pretty blocky sphere around you, with the closest point being 114 blocks away from you and the farthest 142 blocks away from you.

But I wouldn't recommend building a sheep farm this big anyway, because the tens of thousands of sheep would definitely lag the server and your client.